# Why is the range for a particle thrown at 90 degree same as that of a particle thrown at 0 degree?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, projectile

There is a derivation given in my book which concludes to the fact that the range is same for two angles of projection, provided they are complementary. I fail to understand this fact. For example, what if we put the angle as 90 and 0 which are complimentary. Practically how is the particle projected at zero degree have 0 range? Isn't rolling a ball on a floor have a range? Or maybe hitting the ball during billiards. Basically at zero degree I feel the motion would become rectilinear.whereas at 90 degree the range is zero as the object goes up and comes down. I have understood it mathematically by putting the angles in the range formula but not practically. Please help.
(This question is not the same as a question I posted earlier. Since there were too many mistakes in that question I decided to post the edited question again although the I edited the question there also but no one seems to be responding.)

Comment: I think the derivation you have in your book assumes that the projectile stops moving the moment it touches the ground, so although a rolling ball has range in real life, the equation you're using doesn't express this fact.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130861/2451

Comment: What is the angle measured against? The ground? What is the velocity of the projectile? How high above the ground is it when it is thrown? The question is still not clear.

Comment: Hi user166748. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: I don't understand why the close reason says "already has an answer" - the supposed duplicate question doesn't appear to have an answer (or it has been deleted and I can't see it).

Comment: @Floris: It's a canned response.

Comment: @KyleKanos - OK, but then maybe closing as duplicate should not be done when the duplicate question has no answer?... although in this case there clearly ought to be just one question, and encouraging a new user to edit the original is a good thing. Still - Danu's answer here is more useful than any answers I see in the original.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I am not supposed to provide such details otherwise the question can be endless....neglecting air friction .....wrt ground projectile and not the sun! Sir these things are quite obvious.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Floris

Comment: The original question has been automatically deleted, so I'm unmarking this as a duplicate. But for future reference, it should have been an edit to the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book that you are following makes the following simplification: The object instantly comes to rest the moment it hits the ground. This is perhaps not completely physically reasonable, but I think you can also understand that the point of the relevant section is to discuss how far one can throw objects, not to provide a detailed discussion of the relevant effects when rolling a ball ;)